# ffmpeg make video from audio, img and vtt subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a video with image audio file and vtt files, that's my command

```
ffmpeg -i F:\speech\media/waves/to_be_translated/python_example_test_GUyqHnh.wav -loop 1 -i F:\speech\waves/img.jpg -vf -filter_complex subtitles=F:\\speech\\media/typedVideos/combinedVideoTyped/zcjgtmrdlscqzina\\subtitles.vtt -map -shortest F:\speech\media/typedVideos/combinedVideoTyped/zcjgtmrdlscqzina\exported-video.mp4
```

but it gives this error:

```
Output #0, webvtt, to 'subtitles=F:\\speech\\media/typedVideos/combinedVideoTyped/zcjgtmrdlscqzina\\subtitles.vtt':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell ffmpeg what to do with the inputs.

There are many ways to skin a cat, here is one simplistic way.

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -f lavfi -i color=size=640x480:color=black -i 'input.wav' -filter_complex "[1][0]overlay[out];[out]subtitles='input.srt'[vid]" -map [vid] -map 2 -shortest -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

We specify 3 inputs, the image, a Libavfilter input virtual device and the audio.

The virtual device generates a black video of a specified size.

The image is overlaid on top of the video, with the subtitles placed on the resulting output.

Finally we map the finished video with the audio into the final output file, an .mp4 which finishes when the shortest element going into it finishes, which will be the audio in this case, as the image and the video have no length per se.